# How can I have coded this better so my code doesn't look so amateurish?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code takes 8 divs and races them across the screen depending on which time value the div was assigned. How can I have coded this better so my code doesn't look so amateurish?

I know I should have used something other than a hard coded 8 in my for-loop but timeArray.length is unavailable since I am removing items from the array with splice.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var timeArray = new Array(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
var shortestTime = timeArray[7];
var fastestPony = {};
var index;

var pony = {
    name: "pony",
    raceTime: -1,
    selected: ""
};

//change the color of the pony when the user clicks on it
$('.pony').bind('click', function() {
    $('.pony').removeClass('selectedPony');
    $(this).addClass('selectedPony');

    //get the pony that the user selected
    pony.selected = $(this);
});

$('#startButton').click(function() { 
    if (pony.selected == "") {
        alert("Please click the pony you think will win the race.");
    }
    else {
        for (i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
        //get a random number from the timeArray
            index = Math.floor(Math.random() * timeArray.length);
            pony.raceTime = timeArray[index];

            //pull the random race time number out of the array 
            //so it can't be assigned to another horse
            timeArray.splice(index, 1);

            //get the fastest pony
            if (pony.raceTime < shortestTime) {
                shortestTime = pony.raceTime;
                fastestPony = $('#pony' + i);
            }

            //award the winner after the ponies have reached the finish line
            if (i == 8) {
                fastestPony.addClass('winner').append(' - Winner!');
            }

            //send the horses on their way to race!
            $('#pony' + i).animate({left: '320px'}, pony.raceTime * 1000);
        }
    }
});

//reset the ponies back to the starting line by reloading the page
$('#resetButton').click(function() {
    document.location.reload(true);
});
});
```

Comment: this would be more appropriate for [codereview.SE]

Comment: `var timeArray = [3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];`

Comment: Don't use the word pony? ask this on the code review stackexchange.

Comment: I didn't know about Code Review. I will post it there.

Comment: don't use `.bind()` - use `.on()` (see [http://api.jquery.com/on/ to understand why - TL;DR `.on()` replaces all other methods for listeners from jquery 1.7.

Comment: I would drop jQuery if you don't want it to look so "amateurish".

Comment: @Ben I've flagged it for migration. You should do the same instead of reposting! Flag and add a comment about migrating it to codereview.se

Comment: I don't see any migration options on this page to click on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a matter of preference and nitpicky-ness, but since you asked...

I've heard that the `on(...)` method is preferred in most circles:

```
$('.pony').on('click', function() {
```

and

```
$('#startButton').on('click', function() {
```

Of course this depends on what version of jQuery you are using and may be completely subjective.

Comment: .on() is not just a preference, it has huge performance gain for scenarios where you have to add 10000 event bindings to 10000 elements. With .on() you would only need to add 1 event binding to the container only, and all 10000 elements would still react to the events you want.

Comment: I agree completely.  I think I mentioned that preference in my answer as well. Based on the context of the OPs question, I find more amateurs use `.bind` or `.click` than `.on`.

Comment: @shanabus You're answer is not really clear on that at all. Especially the last sentence makes it hard to tell you are saying it has a huge performance gain.

Comment: @PeeHaa I am not sure I agree with that.  I do not speak to the performance whatsoever. The term I used is 'completely subjective' - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjectivity